# Why is it that the conformal anomaly has to be scale invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, quantum-anomalies

When reading about conformal anomalies, such as in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9609138v1.pdf) it is often stated that the anomaly (ie. $ \delta W[g]/ \delta \sigma$ where $ W[g]$ is the quantum effective action for gravity)  must be local and scale invariant.

Could somebody explain why that it?

Thank you.

Comment: Anomalies come from divergences, and divergences have to be local, at least in the context of the perturbation theory. This is because each differentiation of the correlation function reduces the superficial index of divergence by one. The divergent part of the diagram is thus a polynomial in momenta and thus local. I guess it answers half the question.

Comment: I think its just how he defines the conformal anomaly. W, the generating functional has scaling dimension 0, and taking the variation with respect to $\sigma$, which also has scaling dimension 0, doesn't change that. 

An easy way to see that W must be dimensionless is that the generator of correlation functions is exp[W].